# How to get byte array of an online mp4 link on client side?

Tags: c#, ajax, arrays, mp4

I'm planning to save an online mp4 link to user's local using embedded server. I can do it from input file control. But now I have to do it for online mp4 video.
What I do for file is to send byte array with parts using file.slice method using ajaxrequest as formdata. Then embedded server gets the bytearray and creates the file.
It is ok for file control, but how can I do it for online mp4 video link?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have implemented mp4handler for nancyfx and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit difficult to understand your question, but I think this is what you're asking for.

How to download the file synchronously - The quick and dirty approach:

```
using System.Net;
var webClient = new WebClient();
webClient.DownloadFile("http://somewebsite.com/theVideo.mp4", @"c:\localPath\theVideo.mp4");
```

How to download the file asynchronously - The better approach:

```
    private void DownloadFile(string url, string localOutputPath)
    {
        var webClient = new WebClient();
        webClient.DownloadFileCompleted += Completed;
        webClient.DownloadProgressChanged += ProgressChanged;
        webClient.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri(url), localOutputPath);
    }

    private void ProgressChanged(object sender, DownloadProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    { 
        Console.WriteLine(e.ProgressPercentage + " %");
    }

    private void Completed(object sender, AsyncCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("File download completed!");
    }
```

If you're downloading onto the client's machine then this might help:
http://pixelscommander.com/en/javascript/javascript-file-download-ignore-content-type/

Alternatively the user could just send the video url (only) to the server, and let the server download the file.

Comment: I need to download directly to user's local not to server. You code will download to server's c directory. This is why I'm using embedded http server (nancyfx). I need to find a way to to get bytearray from client side and send data to embedded http server using ajaxrequest.

Comment: So let me try rephrase the problem.
1. You'd like the user to find a video online somewhere.
2. They would then copy the url and paste it into a text box
3. The user's browser would then start downloading the video bytes and send the bytes onto another server somewhere
= Lots of traffic for the client/user
= Lots of wasted time for the user

If that's the case then I would do things differently:
1. User finds and copies video url
2. User pastes url it into a text box
3. That url (only) is sent to the server
4. The server downloads the video
= Video is only downloaded once

Comment: Here is the scenario: We will have two types of members. Some of them will use online storage to store video files and some of them will use their shared network storage to keep video files. So for the second types of members we need to download the video directly to their network storage without going through the server since the files could be GB sizes.The only way to do this is using embedded server as I searched.I could copy a file from user's desktop to user's network storage with this way. Youtube, vimeo, dailymotion mp4 links is found automatically,I need to save the mp4 directly client